# Setting Named User ID Urban Airship

Tags: android, xamarin, urbanairship.com

I have recently added Urban Airship to our application for Push Notifications. After deploying to production, we have received a warning from Urban Airship that it is not recommended to send e-mail addresses as device tags.

Therefore, I will now set them as Named User IDs like this;

```
UAirship.Shared().PushManager.NamedUser.Id = "abc@abc.com";
```

My question is whether this is safe or not?

The default tutorial for setting named user ids from android side does not include any recommendation to hash the data but in this link; [Named Users](http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic-guides/mobile-data-bridge.html#named-users), it states that;

> named_user_id is a unique identifier for the Named User. This string serves as the user identifier that links your CRM data with urban airship. Try to choose a simple yet secure identifier, such as a hash of a user’s email address.

While setting the named user id, should I be hashing the e-mail address or does the component do that itself automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You should be performing the hashing; the Urban Airship named users API will store whatever string you provide as the id (you can verify this by [listing the named users you've created](http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#listing); the idea is to avoid storing personal information, but also to pick an identifier that is unlikely to change. Using a hash of the email address is only one suggestion; you could use any identifier you like so long as it's unique to each named user, and that you can reproduce it when associating multiple devices.